# PHP sites as subfolders in a Drupal installation

Tags: php, drupal, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a drupal site that was on shared hosting with other non-drupal sites. Of course there's a primary domain and subfolders.

I recently moved the drupal site to be the primary domain, so all the other non-drupal sites are as subfolders.

Since I've done this however, none of the other non-drupal sites is displaying.

But when I disable the .htaccess file, the non-drupal sites display, but the drupal site on the primary domain begins to have issues.

Does anyone know the fix for this .htaccess file to allow non-drupal sites to be subfolders of a drupal site?

Comment: Based on context, you mean *subfolder*, not *subdomain*.

Answer (score 4):

The Drupal Handbook has an entry about [configuring .htaccess to ignore certain subfolders](http://drupal.org/node/30334). Namely, given two subfolders `/folder1/` and `/folder2/`, you'd add the following immediately after `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder1/" [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/folder2/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```